# Pass arguments to command groups, python fire

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, python-fire

How can I pass the arguments `val` and `code` to the group `get`

- #### Code so far

```py
import fire

class Get:

    def __init__(self, val="no", code=""):

        self.val = val
        self.code = code


    def get(self):
        return f"called get {self.val} {self.code}"

    def get_many(self):
        return f"called get many {self.val}"


class Pipeline:

    def __init__(self,):
        self.get = Get()

def main():
    fire.Fire(Pipeline)
```

- ##### The error I Got

```sh
$> my_p get --code="test" --val="yes" get

ERROR: Could not consume arg: --code=test
Usage: my_p get get <command>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/master/docs/guide.md#version-4-firefireclass

you need to change :

```
self.get = Get
```

Besides, I recommend to not use the same name in "get" function in class Get. It is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import fire


class Get(object):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

    def get(self):
        return f"called get {self.attr.val} {self.attr.code}"

    def get_many(self):
        return f"called get many {self.attr.val}"


class Pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            self.__dict__[key] = kwargs.get(key, val)
        self.get = Get(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fire.Fire(Pipeline)
```

output

```
python my_p.py get --code="test" --val="yes" get
called get yes test
```